# Run C++ console application as AppContainer using manifest

Tags: c++, visual-studio, appcontainer

I have a Win C++ console application that I want to always run as AppContainer. I know I can run it as AppContainer from external code using [`CreateAppContainerProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createappcontainerprofile).
But is there an option to declare "Run As AppContainer" in applicaiton manifest file? such that when user double clicks the exe, it will run as AppContainer (similar to defining in manifest "Run as Administrator" using `requestedExecutionLevel` element)

[I see that I can [package my application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps), but this turns my C++ Application into packaged C# application that requires installation and just complicates it for me without need]

Answer (score 0):

I checked the document: [Application manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests).
There is no option related to appcontainer.